# configuring ioslides background with css

Tags: css, r, markdown, rstudio, ioslides

How can I remove the grey gradient at the bottom of slides generated with ioslides using Rstudio markdown? I managed to remove it from the title slide using custom css:

```
.title-slide {
 background-color: white; 
}
```

I have not succeeded in removing it from all other slides, however. The [ioslides markdown documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html#custom_css) provides very little documentation of the default css used and how to modify it. I have looked at [default.css](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/ioslides/ioslides-13.5.1/theme/css/default.css) on Github. Is there any other documentation that one can use in customising the appearance of ioslides using css?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem. The following css code seems to remove the gradient background:

```
slides > slide.backdrop {
  background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me worked the following:

```
slides > slide.backdrop {
  background: none !important;
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue! By adding the following lines in the CSS file the grey gradient at the bottom is removed.

```
slides > slide {
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #ffffff 85%, #ffffff);
  background-color: white;
  }
```